# Gitlab CI Build failed gitlab-runner-prebuilt.tar.xz: no such file or directory

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I just installed Gitlab Runner on my dev machine (Ubuntu 17.10) for testing.
When I run the runner I got:

```
$: sudo gitlab-runner exec docker test       
   Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner dev (1.4.2)
   Using Docker executor with image php:5.6 ...
   ERROR: Build failed (system failure): open /var/lib/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-prebuilt.tar.xz: no such file or directory
   FATAL: open /var/lib/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-prebuilt.tar.xz: no such file or directory
```

.gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: php:5.6

before_script:
  - php -v

stages:
  - test

test:
  script:
  - php -v
```

Current installation process:

```
sudo apt-get install gitlab-runner
```

Output:

```
...
Configuring gitlab-ci-multi-runner (1.4.2+dfsg-1) ...
I: generating GitLab Runner Docker image. This may take a while...
E: No mirror specified and no default available
W: please run 'sudo /usr/lib/gitlab-runner/mk-prebuilt-images.sh' to generate Docker image.
...
```

So I did:

```
$: sudo /usr/lib/gitlab-runner/mk-prebuilt-images.sh
   I: generating GitLab Runner Docker image. This may take a while...
   E: No mirror specified and no default available
```

Answer (score 66):

Got the same problem today. Turns out `cdebootstrap` command in `usr/lib/gitlab-runner/mk-prebuilt-images.sh` is causing this error message:

```
cdebootstrap \
     --flavour=minimal \
     --exclude="dmsetup,e2fsprogs,init,systemd-sysv,systemd,udev" \
     --include="bash,ca-certificates,git,netcat-traditional" \
     stable ./debian-minbase
```

Change the last line to:

```
     stable ./debian-minbase https://deb.debian.org/debian/
```

The script should now proceed without any errors. More info on debootstrap can be found [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap).

Comment: I'm amazed at how it's now over a year later and I installed gitlab-runner yesterday on 18.04 and this is still how I fixed it...

Comment: Same here, had no problem before, I updated to 18.04 and the problem appeared, editing this line fixed it

Comment: Any particular reason why you are putting an `http` instead of an `https` URL there?

Comment: @us2012 Good point! I didn't check it with https, though. If you can confirm that it works with https, I'll edit the answer to use this protocol instead.

Comment: Did not help on Elementary OS 5.0 Juno

Comment: This is the correct answer for Ubuntu 18.04. Just tried today. Thanks!

Comment: Install cdebootstrap, replace ```cdebootstrap stable ./debian-minbase``` with ```cdebootstrap stable ./debian-minbase https://deb.debian.org/debian/``` and check logs ```nano /var/cache/gitlab-runner/cdebootstrap.log```. I have a problem with RSA 6D33866EDD8FFA41C0143AEDDCC9EFBF77E11517.

Comment: @Max Did you use the proper Repo for gitlab-runner as stated in https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html ?

I installed `gitlab-runner` without it and got the ubuntu delivered version 10.x where it was still buggy. Using the newest version from the repo fixed it for me.

Comment: Workaround is in this issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1605

Answer (score 14):

The currently accepted answer (editing `mk-prebuilt-images.sh` script) didn't worked for me, but I found how to fix it for my case:

I was wrong when just doing `apt-get install gitlab-runner`, and checked my version:

```
$ gitlab-runner -v
Version:      10.5.0
```

which is **not the latest version**, I expected to have the version 12.

So I found this installation guide:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/docs/install/linux-repository.md

This guide says to **add an up-to-date repository**:

```
# For Debian/Ubuntu/Mint
curl -L https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-runner/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

# For RHEL/CentOS/Fedora
curl -L https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-runner/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
```

Then install it:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install gitlab-runner
```

And now I have:

```
$ gitlab-runner -v
Version:      12.3.0
```

And I can run jobs locally.

Comment: with 12.6.0
also need to manualy create dir 
'sudo mkdir /var/lib/gitlab-runner'
after install

Comment: Installed 13.8.0 that way and works right out of the box

Answer (score 3):

You can try this command to fix your issue:

```
$ sudo find / -name "mk-prebuilt-images.sh"
```

Most likely it will then find

```
/usr/lib/gitlab-runner/mk-prebuilt-images.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on ubuntu 18.04 which was caused because I accidentally installed the native gitlab-runner package which was version 10.5 (instead of 12.2.0).
The fix for this is provided in the gitlab-runner [installation guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/docs/install/linux-repository.md#apt-pinning).

I just had to manually set the source for the package by adding a pinning configuration file with the following content:

```sh
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-gitlab-runner.pref
Explanation: Prefer GitLab provided packages over the Debian native ones
Package: gitlab-runner
Pin: origin packages.gitlab.com
Pin-Priority: 1001
EOF
```

After that i was able to install gitlab-runner version 12.2.0 and the above mention issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

As the workaround can use GitLab-Runner docker image. I found this approach https://angristan.xyz/build-push-docker-images-gitlab-ci/ the best one <sub>(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56765508/3743145)</sub>

More info is in official documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem on Linux Mint 19.3. I was stuck with version 10.5 even when getting the packages from gitlab.com

```
deb https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-runner/linuxmint/ tricia main
deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-runner/linuxmint/ tricia main
```

I fell back to get the .deb package and installed it manually (follow this [howto](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html) ).

```
curl -LJO https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/deb/gitlab-runner_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i ./gitlab-runner_amd64.deb
```

It works perfectly.