# gitlab ci failing with custom runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to create a custom gitlab-runner to run a docker process, following:

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/ci/docker/using_docker_build.md

I tried the second approach in which I registered a runner using:

> sudo gitlab-runner register -n \   --url https://gitlab.com/ \
>   --registration-token xxx \   --executor docker \   --description "My Docker Runner" \   --docker-image "docker:stable" \   --docker-volumes
>   /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

However,at gitlab, whenever the pipeline starts I'm facing the following error:

> ERROR: Failed to create container volume for /builds/xxx Unable to
>   load image: gitlab-runner-prebuilt: "open
>   /var/lib/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-prebuilt.tar.xz: no such file or
>   directory"

I can't find much information online, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For The record, I got it working following this tutorial

https://angristan.xyz/build-push-docker-images-gitlab-ci/

Since the docker image worked, I suspect there's something wrong with the debian gitlab-runner distribution